# TeX question: how to switch between languages?

Tags: languages, plain-tex, amstex

I am using TeX, with the macro package AmS-TeX. I'd like to use it with the Italian language, so that words are hyphenated the right way (e.g. the Italian word 'distante' should be broken as di-stante; TeX instead breaks it as dis-tante, like it would break the English word 'distant').

In addition, is it possible to switch between different languages in the same document? If so, then how?

I have found solution to this problem only for LaTeX; I need, instead, a solution for TeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX (from another Italian fellow)! Are you really sure you want to use a format which has been dead for several years?

Comment: wow amstex, archaeology in action:-)

Comment: Thank you for the welcome.  I'm learning TeX and I want to use a 'format' which is best suitable for mathematical writings. (I don't like LaTeX.) Do you think plain TeX or other formats should be better using? What do you suggest me?

Comment: Luatex (which should be Amstex compatible) offers support for using several different hyphenation dictionaries with a document that may provide a solution that is probably rather easier than @egreg's solution.  I'd post an answer, but I have no experience with this; take a look at section 4.7 of the refman: http://www.luatex.org/svn/trunk/manual/luatexref-t.pdf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## First part of the procedure

This procedure assumes you're running TeX Live on a Unix box.

1. Go in a working directory just to be sure you don't overwrite anything.
2. Prepare a file `bplain.cnf` containing the line

   ```
   bplain pdftex language.dat -translate-file=cp227.tcx *bplain.ini
   ```
3. Run the following command line

   ```
   fmtutil --cnffile bplain.cnf --fmtdir . --all
   ```
4. Do the command

   ```
   mv pdftex/bplain.fmt .
   ```
5. Process the test file `matteo.tex` shown below with

   ```
   pdftex -fmt bplain -output-format pdf matteo
   ```

Here is the test file

```
% test file matteo.tex
% activate italian
\language\csname l@italian\endcsname
\lccode`'=`'
\righthyphenmin=2
%%%

\overfullrule=0pt % just for the example

\input amstex
\documentstyle{amsppt}

\topmatter
\title A paper\endtitle
\author Matteo\endauthor
\endtopmatter

\document

\vbox{\hsize=3pt\hskip0pt % show some hyphenations
 distante
 amicizia
 dell'amicizia
 ricordo
}

\enddocument
```

And here is the output

[image]

Now you can move `bplain.fmt` in some place where TeX Live can find it; for instance

```
~/texmf/web2c/pdftex
```

(or `~/Library/texmf/web2c/pdftex` on Mac OS X). The command line above will work from any directory.

If you're bold, steps 3 and 4 and the final move of `bplain.fmt` file can be done in one step by

```
fmtutil --cnffile bplain.cnf --fmtdir $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME) --all
```

## Second part of the procedure

Now you should have a working setup. Add the following alias to your `.bashrc` file:

```
alias bpdftex='pdftex -fmt bplain -output-format pdf'
```

and, when you'll open a new shell, you'll be able to run

```
bpdftex matteo
```

A more complicated example file showing how to switch languages:

```
\catcode`@=11
\def\italian{%
  \language\l@italian
  \lccode`'=`'
  \righthyphenmin=2
}
\def\english{%
  \language\l@english
  \lccode`'=0
  \righthyphenmin=3
}
% you can add other languages, if you want
\catcode`@=12
\english % initialization
%%%

\overfullrule=0pt % just for the example

\input amstex
\documentstyle{amsppt}

\topmatter
\title A paper\endtitle
\author Matteo\endauthor
\endtopmatter

\document

% this will use English hyphenation
\vbox{\hsize=3pt\hskip0pt % show some hyphenations
 distance
 pleasure
 confidential
 record
}

\medskip\hrule\smallskip

\italian % this will use Italian hyphenation
\vbox{\hsize=3pt\hskip0pt % show some hyphenations
 distante
 amicizia
 dell'amicizia
 ricordo 
}

\enddocument
```

[image]

## Third part of the procedure

**Switch to LaTeX**

Comment: The command
fmtutil --cnffile bplain.cnf --fmtdir . --all
doesn't work

Comment: It says:

fmtutil: config file `bplain.cnf' not found (ls-R missing?).

Comment: @Matteo Oh, sorry, I wrote the file name wrongly! Check the fixed answer.

Comment: I haven't saved any bplain.cnf: you haven't said me to do  it. I've only created the file matteo.cnf

Comment: @Matteo I changed the file name; it should be `bplain.cnf`, not `matteo.cnf`

Comment: Ok, the test document with the right hyphenations has been created. Now, what to do exactly? I have Ubuntu with TeX Live.

Comment: And if I want to switch back to English in the same document where I'm using Italian?  In addition, isn't there a way to compile just by writing pdftex <filename> without bother writing in full pdftex -fmt bplain -output-format pdf <filename> ?

Comment: @Matteo I added something. But, really, ***don't*** use AMS-TeX. There's absolutely no reason for using it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12119/discussion-between-matteo-and-egreg)

Comment: Why doesn't `\uselanguage{italian}` hyphenate? `\uselanguage{finnish}`, for example, works just fine.

Comment: @morbusg I get `Undefined control sequence \uselanguage`

Comment: \uselanguage{italian} works, but only with pdftex. Instead, with tex acts as egreg said

Comment: But with \uselanguage{italian} the word "dell'amicizia" doesn't get hyphenated at all. The other words behave the same

Answer (score 1):

You may also try egreg's [hyplain](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyplain) as a format for Plain TeX. It requires only three files to install, and the documentation is a two page leaflet.